# Access CrossTab style report using text and not summary values

Tags: ms-access, report, crosstab

I'm using Access 2007.

I'm struggling to produce a report in a specific format. The style of the report is a crosstab, but I wish to replace the summary values with text.

Examples of the styles of report can be seen [here](http://www.coe.int/t/dg4/education/elp/elp-reg/Source/assessement_grid/assessment_grid_english.pdf)
.

I can reproduce the report (nearly), but in a CrossTab, instead of the text for each of the levels, I have a summary value, which in my query is always 'one' for the count of the text values :)

How can I produce a report like this within Access??

Any help/pointers will be gratefully received.